# How can I redact passwords in a Charles Proxy trace

Tags: http, charles-proxy

I need to document an HTTP authentication issue with a [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) trace but I want to redact the passwords in the resulting trace file.

Hand-editing the binary `.chls` file produced by the "Save" menu command results in a corrupted file, so that is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving the trace to a `.chls` file, export it with the "File > Export..." menu command to an "XML Session File".

[image]

You can then edit the resulting XML file before handing it off, and the recipient will be able to import it into Charles with the "File > Import..." command and view it.